# Python - How to predict feature sales value by feeding other parameters? Using LSTM or?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, regression, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I am new to this Regression world and I have a nerd question, you may say.

Actually I was trying to solve a problem to predict future sales in my organization.
I have collected all the **data** for last year. My data includes (for each day):

1. Total Sales(count)
2. Temperature
3. Wind Direction
4. Precipitation
5. Day of week (i.e 1 or 2 or 3.. or 7)
6. Whether a working day or not.
   etc.

**My goal** : 
 1. I will train a model so that if I give the input of all the values of 2 to 7 (i.e of data, of the day that I want to predict, which is neither in test nor test data) and it will give me the predicted value of 1 (i.e Total Sales).

**I Tried** :
 1. 1st I tried with a *Univariate LSTM* model(i.e with total sales from past one year data, predict the next data). But, I couldn't feed the other data as input.

2. Then I tried a *Multivariate LSTM* model, but this would predict all of the data for the next series.
3. Then I searched for many tutorials to solve the problem. Such as  :  [This video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_qX2V9iBeQ) which uses LSTM for electricity bill consumption, but it only shows the model building and not how to implement it.
4. I came with another question : [from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57167001/predicting-future-values-in-a-multivariate-time-forecasting-lstm-model). But here, the user seems to be moving to reinforcement learning.

**Conclusion**  : What should i do to solve such problems? How to predict future sales count by feeding the data for that day?